# Distance Vector Routing Algorithm advertising with poisened reverse

Tags: algorithm, vector, distance

[image: the image of the diagram]

I'm having an issue with a question with distance vector routhing algorithm this is the question : The figure depicts an autonomous system (AS) comprising of 6 routers connected
via certain links, with the numbers indicating the time cost for each link between the
routers. The distance vector algorithm is used for routing packets.
a) Write the initial distance table of Router C

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should describe what your "issue" is, and what efforts you've made to solving this problem, rather then just asking for other to solve it for you.

Comment: i dont understand this thats the problem . i dont know where to research for this type of question thats why im asking .

Comment: Did you try googling "distance vector algorithm"?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean befor C getting update its table , that will be

```
to A via A cost =2
to C via C cost =0
to D via D cost =1
to F via F cost =18
```